# Is it possible to "go back" to grub after booting linux

Tags: linux, boot, grub, secure-boot

I am trying to enable secureboot so I can forget about it when switching between windows and linux through dualboot. However, grubs newer versions don't allow mods to be inserted after boot, so I need to be able to find the modules that grub uses after linux has been booted so I can add them to the grub compilation command. How can I do this? Can I return to the grub command line after booting linux to run `lsmod`?

Answer (score 2):

Secure boot does not prevent loading modules after boot.  However, if the kernel notices it was booted with secure boot on, it may insist that the kernel modules pass secure boot tests (i.e., they must be signed).

To be pedantic, grub doesn't have a "compilation command".  However, when drivers and the kernel are updated, an initrd is frequently built and then added to the grub configuration.   The initrd contains (among other things) drivers that must be loaded at boot time (typically video drivers that need to be initialized early and disk drivers, without which booting can't continue).

If the kernel modules you have came with the kernel and are from one of the major linux distributions, they should already be signed and should work with secure boot.  If you are using a third party driver, especially one that uses DKMS to automatically build, it is possible to create a MOK (Machine Owner's Key), enroll it in your bios, and sign the driver with it so that it can load.

Note that adding the driver to the initrd and loading it with grub will not work if it isn't also signed.  So "going back to grub" to use lmod not only isn't possible, it isn't useful and won't accomplish what you need.  Instead, look into creating and enrolling a MOK and signing your kernel driver with it.

Comment: I have created a MOK with shim and signed grub and the kernel with it, however whenever I try to load a module with grub, I get the error "prohibited by secure boot policy"

Comment: Did you successfully enroll the MOK in your bios?

Comment: yes I do have mok enrolled into my bios I followed the arch linux wiki page for secure boot [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot#Shim_with_key_and_GRUB) and it says that to fix the error certain modules need to be preloaded

Comment: To pre-load modules, they have to be in initrd.  There's a file somewhere where you can add them, and anotehr file somewhere that force loads them in the initrd.  Once you've added the modules to those, you rebuild the initrd with some command I can't immediately remember.   If you can't figure out that part, ask it in another question.

Comment: On the other hand, if what you meant by "preload" is that they have to be loaded before your target module, if your kernel is built and installed correctly, the modprobe command should take care of loading dependencies.

Comment: this post is referring to grub modules not kernel modules